# How to move list of robots with unit-size move any time?

Tags: python, list, numpy

Suppose I have robots whose position is represented by a pair of integer coordinates on the Cartesian axis system.

That is, the locations of list of robots look like this:

```
robots_positions = [[2, 13], [2, 12], [2, 8], [3, 14]]
```

Now, I want to randomly generate unit-size move (up, down, right, left, stay in place) for each of the robots, without constraints. Something like:

```
moves_list = ["up", "up", "down", "stay"] # Each movement corresponds to one robot from the list above.
```

Next, I would like to add the `moves_list` to the `robots_positions` list to get the new location of each of the robots.

So in our case, the desired result is:

```
robots_positions + moves_list = [[2, 14], [2, 13], [2, 7], [3, 14]]
```

How can I do that easily?

What I was trying to do:

1. I drew a number thas is the size of the number of robots to the power of five:

   `np.power(len(robots_positions), 5)`
2. I tried to move the number to base five, then treat each digit as representing a direction of motion for one of the robots. I'm already stuck here ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a bunch of `if-elif` to add different things depending on the direction of movement, or you can simply use a dictionary that tells you what change each direction causes. For example,

```
directions = {"up": [0, 1], "down": [0, -1], "left": [-1, 0], "right": [1, 0], "stay": [0, 0]}

robots_positions = [[2, 13], [2, 12], [2, 8], [3, 14]] 
moves_list = ["up", "up", "down", "stay"]
```

Then, you can use `zip` to iterate over both `robots_positions` and `moves_list` together, get the delta from the `directions` dictionary, and add it to the current position

```
for robot_num, (pos, move) in enumerate(zip(robots_positions, moves_list)):
    delta = directions.get(move, [0, 0]) # If move doesn't exist, do nothing
    new_pos = [p + d for p, d in zip(pos, delta)]
    robots_positions[robot_num] = new_pos
```

Or, as a list-comprehension:

```
robots_positions = [ [p + d for p, d in zip(pos, directions.get(move, [0, 0]))] for pos, move in zip(robots_positions, moves_list)]
```

Now we have our new positions:

```
[[2, 14], [2, 13], [2, 7], [3, 14]]
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code:

```
def movement(robots_positions,moves_list):
    for i in range(len(robots_positions)):
        if moves_list[i]=="up":
            robots_positions[i][1]=robots_positions[i][1]+1
        elif moves_list[i]=="down":
            robots_positions[i][1]=robots_positions[i][1]-1
        elif moves_list[i]=="left":
            robots_positions[i][0]=robots_positions[i][0]-1
        elif moves_list[i]=="right":
            robots_positions[i][0]=robots_positions[i][0]+1
        elif moves_list[i]=="stay":
            pass
        else:
            print('Invalid command in list')
    return robots_positions

robots_positions = [[2, 13], [2, 12], [2, 8], [3, 14]] 
moves_list = ["up", "up", "down", "stay"] # Each movement corresponds to one robot from the list above.
print(movement(robots_positions,moves_list))
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_

Comment: Actually, I am new here and I felt that this is very simple if else program that's why I didn't mention any details. Thanks for the advice